# How do I terminate coaxial cable in a crimp on F type connector?

Tags: wiring, data-wiring, coaxial-cable

I've got some coaxial cable, and I'd like to put F type connectors on the end so I can use the cable to connect my TV to the Cable box.  How do I put ends on the cable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first step is to cut the cable to length.  You can use any tool capable of cutting the cable, personally I reach for my trusty lineman pliers.

[image: My Lineman Pliers]

Once you cut the cable, it will look something like this

[image: Cut Cable]

Now that the cable is the proper length, you'll have to strip the insulation off. Again, you can use any tool capable of stripping the insulation without damaging the inner cable.  Personally, I use a tool specifically designed for the job.

[image: Coaxial Cable Stripper]

With this tool, you simply

- Push in the button on the end.
- Slide the cut end of the wire into the hole, until it hits the stop.
- Release the button.
- Rotate the tool around the cable a couple times.
- Pull the tool off of the cable.

When you're done, you'll have a perfectly stripped cable.

[image: Stripped Coaxial Cable]

Next you'll carefully bend the braiding back over the insulation (this step may vary, depending on the connector being used. Consult the documentation with the connector).

[image: Braiding Bent Back]

In this case, I'll be using a crimp on connector like this (twist on connectors are also available).

[image: Crimp on F Type Connector]

Push the stripped cable end up into the connector.

[image: End on Cable]

Make sure you push the cable in far enough, so the inner insulation starts to peek through the hole inside the connector.

[image: Cable Properly Inserted in Connector]

Finally, using a crimping tool.

[image: Cable End Crimping Tool]

Place the cable end into the crimping tool, and squeeze the handle.

[image: Cable in Crimping Tool]

---

#### Note:

Twist-on F type connectors are available, in which case you'll not need the crimping tool. However, I've had poor results with the twist-on variety, and much prefer the crimp connectors.

Comment: Twist-on-Pull-off... Watch out for over-compression on the tool. The end-piece on the connector presses together till the metal pieces meet or there's a slightly compressed plastic band showing where they meet depending on construction. The tool has an adjustment. If you're getting bent metal, it needs to be backed off. Nice tutorial, many years ago, I invested in the tools and did my own wiring for the cable install. House wiring has never been an issue when I have signal problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's good habit to also wrap the metal ends where the connectors attach to the wire w/ electrical tape. I like the twist ons, less hassle and work well.  Make sure the insulation completely pulled back from the sheath (foil).